# 'MPTConfig' object has no attribute 'hidden_size'

Tags: databricks, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, deepspeed

I am attempting to finetune an MPT model with DeepSpeed on Databricks, but I am running into this AttributeError. Here is a MRE of my code below:

```
import transformers
from transformers import AutoConfig

model_path = 'mosaicml/mpt-7b'
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model_path, trust_remote_code=True)
model_hidden_size = config.hidden_size

AttributeError: 'MPTConfig' object has no attribute 'hidden_size'
```

I need this `model_hidden_size` variable so I can use it in this code:

```
deepspeed_config["hidden_size"] = model_hidden_size
deepspeed_config["zero_optimization"]["reduce_bucket_size"] = model_hidden_size*model_hidden_size
deepspeed_config["zero_optimization"]["stage3_prefetch_bucket_size"] = 0.9 * model_hidden_size * model_hidden_size
deepspeed_config["zero_optimization"]["stage3_param_persistence_threshold"] = 10 * model_hidden_size
```

Do I need to open a feature request on the MPT github? Should I try and use model foundry instead of Huggingface Transformers? Or is this deepspeed_config code unnecessary for the actual finetuning process? I am using Zero stage 3.